# haskell convert Integer to String without show

Tags: haskell

Is there a way to convert an Integer to String in Haskell without using show?

The problem is that in my code I have already declared a show instance.

```
instance Show ZZ where
    show zz = toHexa (zzToInt zz)
```

So that the program throws the following error when I try to use show at another position

`Ambiguous variable occurrence "show"`

The way I try to use the "normal" show is the following:

```
toBin :: Int -> String
toBin 0 = "0"
toBin 1 = "1"
toBin n
 | n `mod` 2 == 0 = show (toBin (n `div` 2)) ++ "0"
 | otherwise = show (toBin (n `div` 2)) ++ "1"
```

So I need another possibility for show

Comment: If you did this, like you here demonstrate, then that is not a problem. But it looks like you defined a *new* function `show` *outside* the `instance Show` scope.

Comment: Can you show exactly how you *use* `show` here? So share the part of the code that throws this error?

Comment: I added it now above

Comment: Although not really a solution to the problem, it looks very "odd" to call `show` a second time, since `toBin (...)` will already return a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `toBin` does not need a call to `show` here. Indeed `toBin` has signature `Int -> String`, so that means that `` toBin (n `div` 2) `` will return a `String`. By calling `show` on that value, you will add double quotes around it (making it look like a string literal).

You thus can implement the `toBin` as:

import Data.Char(intToDigit)

```
toBin :: Int -> String
toBin 0 = "0"
toBin 1 = "1"
toBin n
  | mod n 2 == 0 = rest ++ "0"
  | otherwise = rest ++ "1"
  where rest = toBin (div n 2)
```

or more efficient:

```
import Data.Char(intToDigit)

toBin :: Int -> String
toBin = reverse . go
    where go 0 = "0"
          go 1 = "1"
          go n = intToDigit (mod n 2) : go (div n 2)
```

For example:

```
Prelude Data.Char> toBin 1425
"10110010001"
```

Defining an extra instance for `Show` is not a problem. In fact the base package of Haskell has several dozens of `Show` instances.

There are two reasons why the call might be ambiguous:

1. it is not clear to the compiler what the type is you call show on. You can sometimes add a type clause to give the compiler a hint, like `show (a :: Int)`;
2. you defined another `show` function *outside* the `instance Show … where …` scope, and thus defined another function.